# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package while running code

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

**Code:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .forms import BookForm
from .models import Book

from django.db import models
```

On running code i am getting this error

**Output: **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/programmer/New Volume/Projects/TradeCred/backend.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .forms import BookForm
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: If you are running on Python 3.X and using dot syntax in import statement, package module can't be run directly or as a main module.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot from beginning. It's must be like : `from forms import BookForm`
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

if removing the '.' did not work, check your file path